# Maven not importing any of the dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I have a Maven project that I would like to add Spring to.

I added a few of the necessary Spring dependencies to the `pom.xml` file, so it looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.55</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

However, in my project's controller file I copied in, Eclipse still gives an import error like

`The import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer cannot be resolved`

This happens even after I click `Update Project` under the Maven menu, as other similar question have answered.

Does anyone have any other ideas what the problem might be?

---

**ADDITIONS**

Here is the project's `.classpath` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="src/main/config"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

And here is the full `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.imray</groupId>
    <artifactId>evac</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>evac Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.55</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>evac</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: post your `.classpath` file for your eclipse project

Comment: Can you add the whole `pom.xml`please?

Comment: run 'mvn clean install' from command line and see if it build right. if not then issue in pom else issue in eclipse project build configuration. I am presuming you are using m2e on eclipse.

Comment: Do you have any kind of setttings in your `.m2/settings.xml` file? If you set a proxy there or any other network settings, that could affect as well. That has happened to me many times when I move from work office to home office.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo where can I find that file?

Comment: @Imray If don't know where it is, most likely you have not changed it. But at any rate, it is at `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` where $HOME is the location of your user's folder. It depends on you OS.

Comment: @Imray you must also check if your eclipse is using the correct settings.xml file or not. Go to window -> preferences -> maven -> user settings. It will show the location from where your eclipse is reading the settings.xml. Also, do you see other dependencies being pulled in or it is just Spring dependencies.

Comment: @Imray did you try a `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on command-line? Did it work?

Comment: @DolphinJava It seems my `settings.xml` doesnt exist in the location it's being pointed to by User Settings.

Comment: @DolphinJava It seems some of the Spring packages are in fact being pulled in, but most aren't. All the dependencies are above, in my question

Comment: Imray, please confirm that the build works from commmand line (`mvn clean package`). Also don't run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` as suggested above if you don't want to break your m2e project.

Comment: @PavelHoral When I command `mvn clean package` in the directory of the project, it seems like its working, but then ends in an error `"[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\Imray\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.0.6.RELEASE\spring-web-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC heade
r (bad signature)"`

Comment: Wipe out the .m2/repository directory and try again. I find this fixes many problems with maven, although it is the so-called *nuclear option*

Comment: @Andy: The maven-eclipse-plugin is obsolete and should not be used.

Comment: Artifacts in your repository are probably broken... you can delete them one by one as the errors come (i.e. start with `C:\Users\Imray\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.0.6.RELEASE`) or as Imray suggested you can delete the whole `~/.m2/repository` directory.

Comment: @chrylis: I know, just wanted to know if it builds from command-line. `mvn clean package` would have been the better approach for that - I agree. (BTW: even if eclipse:eclipse doesn't work properly, it should not do any harm, though)

Comment: @Andy It *will* do harm because it overwrites the Eclipse control files. Users will have to re-import and will lose any custom settings. Until then, they'll simply get inexplicable failures.

Comment: Deleting repository folder didn't help :-(